# Using calculated property setter causes "Cannot assign to the result of this expression"

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to access enum calculated property "Cannot assign to the result of this expression" error mesage appears. What am I doing wrong?

```
enum Switchers:String {
    case SomeOption = "SomeOption"
    var defaults:Bool {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(self.rawValue)
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

func UseSwitchers () {
    let state = Switchers.SomeOption.defaults
    Switchers.SomeOption.defaults = !state // Error: Cannot assign to the result of this expression
}
```

### Edit:

To access defaults as properties I ended up with this:

```
struct Preferences {
    private enum Keys: String {
        case SomeOption = "SomeOption"
    }
    static func setUp () {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults([Keys.SomeOption.rawValue:true])
    }

    static var someOption: Bool {
        get {
            return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(Keys.SomeOption.rawValue)
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: Keys.SomeOption.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

func UsePreferences () {
    Preferences.setUp()
    let someOption = Preferences.someOption
    Preferences.someOption = !someOption
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Switchers.SomeOption.defaults = !state
```

is equivalent to

```
let z = Switchers.SomeOption
z.defaults = !state
```

assignment is not allowed because `z` is immutable.

To fix it, you can do

```
var z = Switchers.SomeOption
z.defaults = !state
```

There's no point writing `Switchers.SomeOption.defaults = !state` anyway (`Switchers.SomeOption` is an "orphaned" value -- you ask for one, and change it's `defaults` property, but never store the value to a variable, so the statement is useless).

Comment: thanks a lot! `let z = Switchers.SomeOption` is a valuable piece of information =)